# Returning the needed value in a class - Java

Tags: java, return, return-value

I am confused about returning the needed value. Here is a part of my code:

```
public class StrNum {

    public static int getInt(String input) {        
        String str = new String(input);
        int result;

        if (str.startsWith("b")) {
            str = str.substring(1);
            result = Integer.parseInt(str, 2);
        }
        else if (str.startsWith("x")) {
            str = str.substring(1);
            result = Integer.parseInt(str, 16);
        }
```

Now, what I need to return is result. When I write `return result;`, it asks me to initialize the variable (and I am aware that it hasn't been initialized). When I use `return result` inside of the `if` statements, Eclipse tells me that I have to return a value.
Where am I being stupid here? I would appreciate a good explanation.

Comment: You should start your variables with a lowercase character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What will the method `getInt()` return if `Str` doesn't start with neither `"b"` or `"x"`? That would be an error because `result` is not being initialized. You could solve this by intializing `result` with a value that you would like to return in that case:

```
int result = -1; // for example
```

**Edit:**

Since you want to use `input` to determine if the number will be parsed as binary or hexadecimal, I would recommend you to add an *else* statement to parse the number in base 10 as default:

```
if (...)
   // ...
else if (...)
   // ...
else
   result = Integer.parseInt(Str);
```

**Note:**

- Try to follow Java naming conventions. Use names like `someVar` for variables/methods and use names like `SomeClass` for classes.
- It's not necessary to create a new string instance `Str`, unless you are going to use the original input later in the same method.
- To create a `String` with the same content you can simply do

  `String str = input;`

Comment: So i have to initialize "result" to the value that doesn't fit the conditions?

Comment: @user3383621 Initializing it to `-1` as in the example by Christian means that you can then test for when you don't get the desired values. In other words, you can use something like, `if (result == -1) System.out.println("You screwed up.");`. You have to initialize result to something, it will not work otherwise. Keep in mind though that `-1` is just an example, you could initialize it to any value that you would want to use to check for errors.

Comment: @Christian yes, i have the "else" clause as well, i just didn't include it in my post. Your explanation is great, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your can either return the result from `if` and also from `else`, provided you are not doing additional calculations after the `else` block.

or simply initialize `result = 0`, it will change anyways before you return.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`int result = 0;`
You must initialize variables before returning them or in other words do result = .  The variable must **always** be initialized no matter what code path your application takes.

Comment: This is partially correct. Instance and class variables are automatically initialized to 0 or null or the equivalent.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong but if the variable has a default value and it is not otherwise defined it would be  considered initialized because it is set to its default value.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `variables with default value`. I am assuming you're referring to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5 In the case of these variables, they will only be initialized, as the specification says, if they are class or instance variables or array components. If these variables are local variables then they are not automatically initialized and have to be initialized by the programmer. Otherwise the program will not compile. This is why I was saying that your answer was partially correct.

Comment: I mean variables types like boolean. You are probably right.